# How to list files recursively from folder in Electron application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, desktop-application

I am trying to upload a folder in electron application

```
 <!--index.html-->

 <input type="file" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory 
 odirectory directory multiple />
 <ul id="listing"></ul>
```

im uploading the folder using `index.html` and passing the folder to `index.js`.

```
    //index.js

    document.getElementById("filepicker").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    let output = document.getElementById("listing");
    let files = event.target.files;
    for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
      let item = document.createElement("li");
      item.innerHTML = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
      output.appendChild(item);
    };
  }, false);
```

im trying to get all the file present inside the selected folder. But when im trying to run this code in my sample electron application im getting only the selected folder name, path,etc,. 
But I can't get the files which is present inside the selected folder.

when I'm uploading the same folder [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) it's showing all files present inside the selected folder.

so please help me to list all the files recursively from the selected folder.

Thanks in advance.